# Why does output shows correct answer for min number of coins required when the change entered is 2.2 but shows the incorrect output when I enter 4.2?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, cs50

I am new to coding and I have been attempting the problem cash.c by CS50. In this problem, the cashier has to provide the minimum number of change using only 25,10,5 and 1 cents respectively.

I have been having trouble with outputs of which I have only mentioned the problem regarding usage of 25 and 10cents. For 2.2 I am supposed to get the answer as 10 and that is what I am getting but for 4.2 I am supposed to get 18 and I am getting answer as 22. Why is this happening?

Useful advice and constructive criticism will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int clear_buffer()
{
int c;
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
}
int main(void)
{
fflush(stdin);
float a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0;
float n;
do
{
printf("The change is ");
}
while ((scanf("%f",&n)!=1) && clear_buffer() || n<0);

while((n-0.25)>=0)
{
    n=n-0.25;
    a++;
}
while((n-0.10)>=0)
{
    n=n-0.10;
    b++;
}
while((n-0.05)>=0)
{
    n=n-0.05;
    c++;
}
while((n-0.01)>=0)
{
    n=n-0.01;
    d++;
}
printf("The minimum coins required are %f", (a+b+c+d));
}
```

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [CS50 stack site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) (and consider joining). This question has been answered on that forum many times. [Here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/greedy-c-works-for-all-numbers-except-4-2) is one example. Just search "4.2" on that site and you will find a host of answers.

Comment: I recommend not using `float` variables or floating-point math for this.  There are some potential gotchas there, though it's not clear to me whether that's the root of your problem.  Instead, use integer variables and integer math, representing money as whole numbers of cents instead of fractional dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is caused by [floating point precision limitations](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FLP00-C.+Understand+the+limitations+of+floating-point+numbers). If you debug the program, as I've shown below in a screenshot using [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) (if you're not yet quite familiar with using GDB on the command line, it is essential you learn, but maybe this can be a good first step). This is quite closely related to https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/greedy-c-works-for-all-numbers-except-4-2 (where there are also some recommendations for potential workarounds/solutions).

[image]
Notice that the value of `n` after subtracting the first `0.10` is indeed less than `0.10`, but is `0.0999998078`  and hence it only thinks there is one dime, not the 2 you are expecting.

As for constructive criticism, your indentation is a little poor (not sure if that's just caused by copy-pasting here or not), you have an unused variable `e`, your `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` variables could be `int`s, not necessarily floats, you have some magic number stuff going on by reusing `0.25`, `0.10`, etc. where these should be pre-declared constants or perhaps even `#define` statements. There are other things as well and if you're truly interested, you may post on the sister site [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) after you've made all of the improvements you can think of.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and feeback. I will definitely learn to debug better. Debugging is something which I have never paid attention to yet to be honest.

Comment: @MohammadAnas You're welcome. It will definitely come in handy if you stick with C or any programming language. gdb will let you view any relevant memory and their values on relevant stacks/frames and is a great learning experience as well.